# technique in getting the id and pass it on ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that has two parameters needed to update a quantity of my item. Now I am having a trouble on how to get the `$product_id` to be pass in my ajax parameter. I don't have any technique on how can i pass the `$product_id` to supply my ajax function. 
By the way i am using laravel.

Here is my code:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
    <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-4">
    <div class="media">
        <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-2/72/product-icon.png" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">&nbsp; {{ $product['item']->product_name }}</a></h4>
            <!-- <span>Status: </span><span class="text-success">&nbsp;<strong>In Stock</strong></span> -->
        </div>
    </div></td>
    <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="productqty" max="{{ $product['maxqty'] }}" min="1" value="{{ $product['qty'] }}">
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

now in my view i want to update the quantity of my item when i click the `input type="number"`

Here is my javascript :

```
$("#productqty").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    updateQty(?,value);
});
```

Here is my javascript. Now i want to get the product_id of the selected input type number. I have many products in it. How can i get my exact product_id when i click the `keyup mouseup` event in my input type that has an id of `$productqty` so that i can supply my ajax function parameter that i put a question mark in it. `updateQty(?,value);` the ? is where i want the `product_id` will be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the event handler, using id will handle only one dom, use class for it: `$(".productqty").bind(..)`
 and

```
<input type="number" class="form-control productqty" id="" max="{{ $product['maxqty'] }}" min="1" value="{{ $product['qty'] }}">
```

the simple way for your need is to put the product id in an input attribute, for now id is free to use, we can use it like:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control productqty" id="{{ $product['id'] }}" max="{{ $product['maxqty'] }}" min="1" value="{{ $product['qty'] }}">
```

and you can get it using jquery.attr(),  `$(this).attr('id');` :

```
$(".productqty").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var product_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = $(this).val();
    updateQty(product_id, value);
});
```